# Access 97 copying field type to other table

Tags: ms-access

In Access 97, I have a table which has fields a and b. Is is possible to find via VB what type are those fields, like varchar or integer? I'm trying to copy the name of the field and its type to another table and replace it if necessary in another table. I can do it using mouse but I don't know how to do it via VB. The result field should contain no data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab that info using DAO in VBA.  Grab the code from this link and put it in a code module:

[Dump Table Details](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Dump-table-details-in-VBA-%28DAO%29)

If you'd like to store that info in a table, change the following block to make INSERTS into your meta table rather than debug.printing:

```
For Each fld In tdf.Fields
  Debug.Print fld.Name,
  Debug.Print FieldTypeName(fld),
  Debug.Print fld.Size,
  Debug.Print GetDescrip(fld)
Next
```

Don't forget to put in a reference to DAO, if necessary, using the instructions in that link.